Pasar un array JSON a una Base de datos SQL
Tengo un array en json, y lo quiero pasar a una BD mysql. Busco una forma más rápida y directa que un INSERT.
options: [
                            { name: "Chick", color: "#ffcd05", class: "\uD83C\uDF3D", rarity: "Common", cash: [3, 7, 65, 400, 2500], time: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], price: [300, 3e3, 3e4, 2e5] },
                            { name: "Chicken", color: "#ed1c24", class: "\uD83C\uDF3D", rarity: "Common", cash: [10, 40, 200, 1400, 1e4], time: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], price: [570, 4e3, 5e4, 8e5] },
                            { name: "Cow", color: "#58595b", class: "\uD83C\uDF3D", rarity: "Common", cash: [25, 75, 1500, 25e3, 25e4], time: [15, 10, 10, 10, 5], price: [500, 9500, 16e4, 4e6] },
                            { name: "Duck", color: "#4ab96d", class: "\uD83C\uDF3D", rarity: "Common", cash: [4, 24, 200, 3e3, 4e4], time: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], price: [450, 4200, 7e4, 11e5] },
                            { name: "Goat", color: "#c59a74", class: "\uD83C\uDF3D", rarity: "Common", cash: [5, 28, 200, 1300, 12e3], time: [3, 3, 2, 2, 2], price: [500, 6400, 45e3, 5e5] },
                            { name: "Horse", color: "#995b3c", class: "\uD83C\uDF3D", rarity: "Common", cash: [5, 20, 270, 1800, 15e3], time: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], price: [550, 8200, 65e3, 6e5] },
                            { name: "Pig", color: "#f6a9cb", class: "\uD83C\uDF3D", rarity: "Common", cash: [20, 50, 1300, 8e3, 8e4], time: [7, 7, 7, 7, 5], price: [400, 11e3, 8e4, 13e5] },
                            { name: "Sheep", color: "#414042", class: "\uD83C\uDF3D", rarity: "Common", cash: [6, 25, 250, 1500, 11e3], time: [3, 3, 3, 2, 2], price: [500, 5e3, 5e4, 43e4] },
                            { name: "Cat", color: "#f49849", class: "\uD83D\uDC3E", rarity: "Common", cash: [5, 18, 170, 1700, 13e3], time: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], price: [480, 5500, 6e4, 5e5] },
                            { name: "Dog", color: "#995b3c", class: "\uD83D\uDC3E", rarity: "Common", cash: [7, 25, 220, 1900, 9e3], time: [3, 3, 2, 2, 1], price: [460, 6600, 7e4, 73e4] },
                            { name: "Goldfish", color: "#f18221", class: "\uD83D\uDC3E", rarity: "Common", cash: [5, 40, 350, 3500, 35e3], time: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], price: [750, 7200, 84e3, 95e4] },
                            { name: "Rabbit", color: "#e7bf9a", class: "\uD83D\uDC3E", rarity: "Common", cash: [3, 18, 185, 800, 7e3], time: [2, 2, 2, 1, 1], price: [500, 5800, 56e3, 55e4] },
                            { name: "Hamster", color: "#ce9176", class: "\uD83D\uDC3E", rarity: "Common", cash: [10, 45, 450, 4500, 45e3], time: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], price: [650, 6500, 8e4, 93e4] },
                            { name: "Turtle", color: "#619a3c", class: "\uD83D\uDC3E", rarity: "Common", cash: [23, 120, 1400, 15e3, 17e4], time: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10], price: [700, 8500, 11e4, 13e5] },
                            { name: "Puppy", color: "#414042", class: "\uD83D\uDC3E", rarity: "Common", cash: [4, 10, 75, 500, 3e3], time: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], price: [450, 4e3, 35e3, 25e4] },
                            { name: "Kitten", color: "#58595b", class: "\uD83D\uDC3E", rarity: "Common", cash: [4, 8, 60, 400, 2e3], time: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], price: [350, 3500, 26e3, 17e4] },
                            { name: "Bear", color: "#995b3c", class: "\uD83C\uDF32", rarity: "Common", cash: [12, 70, 550, 4500, 1e5], time: [7, 7, 6, 5, 5], price: [550, 5500, 63e3, 16e5] },
                            { name: "Moose", color: "#995b3c", class: "\uD83C\uDF32", rarity: "Common", cash: [8, 45, 400, 3500, 26e3], time: [5, 5, 4, 4, 3], price: [520, 6500, 58e3, 7e5] },
                            { name: "Fox", color: "#f49849", class: "\uD83C\uDF32", rarity: "Common", cash: [7, 15, 80, 550, 3e3], time: [2, 2, 1, 1, 1], price: [400, 4e3, 36e3, 24e4] },
                            { name: "Raccoon", color: "#6d6e71", class: "\uD83C\uDF32", rarity: "Common", cash: [5, 14, 185, 1900, 19e3], time: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], price: [400, 5e3, 71e3, 8e5] },
                            { name: "Squirrel", color: "#d25927", class: "\uD83C\uDF32", rarity: "Common", cash: [3, 10, 65, 470, 2600], time: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], price: [420, 3600, 32e3, 21e4] },
                            { name: "Owl", color: "#594a42", class: "\uD83C\uDF32", rarity: "Common", cash: [4, 17, 155, 1500, 15e3], time: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], price: [500, 4800, 55e3, 58e4] },
                            { name: "Hedgehog", color: "#3f312b", class: "\uD83C\uDF32", rarity: "Common", cash: [11, 37, 340, 2200, 3e4], time: [5, 4, 3, 2, 2], price: [540, 7e3, 77e3, 12e5] },
                            { name: "Seal", color: "#7ca1d5", class: "❄️", rarity: "Common", cash: [6, 17, 150, 1200, 13e3], time: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], price: [480, 4500, 43e3, 52e4] },
                            { name: "Arctic Fox", color: "#7ca1d5", class: "❄️", rarity: "Common", cash: [5, 18, 180, 850, 8500], time: [2, 2, 2, 1, 1], price: [520, 550, 61e3, 68e4] },
                            { name: "Snowy Owl", color: "#feda3f", class: "❄️", rarity: "Common", cash: [5, 20, 190, 1900, 16e3], time: [3, 3, 2, 2, 2], price: [370, 5300, 76e3, 62e4] },
                            { name: "Arctic Hare", color: "#7ca1d5", class: "❄️", rarity: "Common", cash: [6, 19, 85, 900, 7e3], time: [2, 2, 1, 1, 1], price: [540, 5200, 66e3, 55e4] },
                            { name: "Penguin", color: "#fb8640", class: "❄️", rarity: "Common", cash: [4, 21, 310, 3200, 33e3], time: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], price: [400, 6500, 76e3, 87e4] },
                            { name: "Baby Penguin", color: "#414042", class: "❄️", rarity: "Common", cash: [3, 8, 70, 450, 2700], time: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], price: [420, 3300, 33e3, 23e4] },
                            { name: "Polar Bear", color: "#7ca1d5", class: "❄️", rarity: "Common", cash: [12, 75, 700, 6500, 85e3], time: [8, 7, 6, 5, 5], price: [630, 7e3, 91e3, 14e5] },
                            { name: "Walrus", color: "#7d4f33", class: "❄️", rarity: "Common", cash: [11, 46, 420, 3700, 51e3], time: [5, 5, 4, 4, 4], price: [550, 6200, 68e3, 1e6] },
                            { name: "Tiger", color: "#f18221", class: "\uD83C\uDF34", rarity: "Common", cash: [6, 20, 100, 975, 7500], time: [3, 3, 1, 1, 1], price: [390, 6e3, 7e4, 61e4] },
                            { name: "Jaguar", color: "#fbb040", class: "\uD83C\uDF34", rarity: "Common", cash: [8, 28, 230, 1600, 17e3], time: [3, 3, 2, 2, 2], price: [390, 6e3, 7e4, 61e4] },
                            { name: "Toucan", color: "#ffca34", class: "\uD83C\uDF34", rarity: "Common", cash: [9, 20, 175, 625, 3800], time: [2, 2, 2, 1, 1], price: [520, 4800, 42e3, 3e5] },
                            { name: "Cockatoo", color: "#7ca1d5", class: "\uD83C\uDF34", rarity: "Common", cash: [6, 35, 160, 1700, 18e3], time: [4, 4, 2, 2, 2], price: [500, 5e3, 63e3, 7e5] },
                            { name: "Macaw", color: "#00aeef", class: "\uD83C\uDF34", rarity: "Common", cash: [3, 8, 85, 850, 8500], time: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], price: [480, 5400, 62e3, 63e4] },
                            { name: "Parrot", color: "#ed1c24", class: "\uD83C\uDF34", rarity: "Common", cash: [3, 9, 90, 900, 9e3], time: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], price: [540, 5700, 65e3, 69e4] },
                            { name: "Panther", color: "#2f2c38", class: "\uD83C\uDF34", rarity: "Common", cash: [12, 28, 215, 2100, 21e3], time: [5, 3, 2, 2, 2], price: [530, 6500, 76e3, 87e4] },
                            { name: "Anaconda", color: "#8a9143", class: "\uD83C\uDF34", rarity: "Common", cash: [3, 15, 85, 1500, 7600], time: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1], price: [410, 5100, 58e3, 59e4] },
                            { name: "Orangutan", color: "#bc6234", class: "\uD83C\uDF34", rarity: "Common", cash: [13, 52, 570, 4300, 7e4], time: [5, 5, 5, 4, 4], price: [600, 7e3, 8e4, 14e5] },
                            { name: "Capuchin", color: "#e0b0a6", class: "\uD83C\uDF34", rarity: "Common", cash: [4, 14, 160, 780, 8200], time: [2, 2, 2, 1, 1], price: [390, 4700, 57e3, 68e4] },
                            { name: "Elf", color: "#a7d054", class: "⚔️", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [5e3, 15e3, 15e4, 15e5, 1e7], time: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], price: [8e5, 9e6, 11e7, 8e8] },
                            { name: "Witch", color: "#4ab96d", class: "⚔️", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [18e3, 6e4, 4e4, 4e6, 35e6], time: [3, 3, 2, 2, 2], price: [11e5, 12e6, 15e7, 14e8] },
                            { name: "Wizard", color: "#5a459c", class: "⚔️", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [19500, 65e3, 44e4, 46e5, 4e6], time: [3, 3, 2, 2, 2], price: [13e5, 135e5, 16e7, 16e8] },
                            { name: "Fairy", color: "#df6d9c", class: "⚔️", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [18500, 6e4, 62e4, 44e5, 38e6], time: [3, 3, 3, 2, 2], price: [12e5, 125e5, 15e6, 15e8] },
                            { name: "Slime Monster", color: "#2fa04a", class: "⚔️", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [35e3, 14e4, 1e6, 11e6, 11e7], time: [5, 5, 4, 4, 4], price: [16e5, 15e6, 2e8, 23e8] },
                            { name: "Jester", color: "#be1e2d", class: "⚔️", rarity: "Rare", cash: [25e3, 1e5, 68e4, 65e5, 32e6], time: [3, 3, 2, 2, 1], price: [2e6, 21e6, 23e7, 26e8] },
                            { name: "Dragon", color: "#2fa04a", class: "⚔️", rarity: "Rare", cash: [36e3, 15e4, 15e5, 15e6, 15e7], time: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], price: [23e5, 24e6, 27e7, 3e9] },
                            { name: "Unicorn", color: "#f6afce", class: "⚔️", rarity: "Epic", cash: [24e3, 15e4, 14e5, 7e6, 75e6], time: [2, 2, 2, 1, 1], price: [45e5, 45e6, 55e7, 65e8] },
                            { name: "Queen", color: "#9e1f63", class: "⚔️", rarity: "Rare", cash: [24e3, 95e3, 95e4, 97e5, 95e6], time: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], price: [19e5, 2e7, 23e7, 25e8] },
                            { name: "King", color: "#ee2640", class: "⚔️", rarity: "Legendary", cash: [75e3, 4e5, 6e6, 9e7, 125e7], time: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], price: [6e6, 95e6, 16e8, 25e9] },
                            { name: "Two of Spades", color: "#414042", class: "\uD83C\uDFF0", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [4500, 14e3, 14e4, 14e5, 9e6], time: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], price: [77e4, 83e5, 98e6, 71e7] },
                            { name: "Eat Me", color: "#d58c55", class: "\uD83C\uDFF0", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [13e3, 45e3, 45e4, 45e5, 5e7], time: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], price: [13e5, 14e6, 16e7, 2e9] },
                            { name: "Drink Me", color: "#dd7399", class: "\uD83C\uDFF0", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [12e3, 4e4, 4e5, 4e6, 45e6], time: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], price: [12e5, 12e6, 14e7, 18e8] },
                            { name: "Alice", color: "#4cc9f5", class: "\uD83C\uDFF0", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [13e3, 42e3, 21e4, 21e5, 23e6], time: [2, 2, 1, 1, 1], price: [12e5, 13e6, 15e7, 19e8] },
                            { name: "Queen of Hearts", color: "#d62027", class: "\uD83C\uDFF0", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [23e3, 87e3, 62e4, 75e5, 9e7], time: [4, 4, 3, 3, 3], price: [13e5, 13e6, 18e7, 24e8] },
                            { name: "Dormouse", color: "#89d6f8", class: "\uD83C\uDFF0", rarity: "Rare", cash: [17e3, 68e3, 7e5, 35e5, 35e6], time: [2, 2, 1, 1, 1], price: [2e6, 22e6, 25e7, 28e8] },
                            { name: "White Rabbit", color: "#ffcd05", class: "\uD83C\uDFF0", rarity: "Rare", cash: [26e3, 105e3, 11e6, 77e5, 72e6], time: [3, 3, 3, 2, 2], price: [2e6, 23e6, 28e7, 29e8] },
                            { name: "Cheshire Cat", color: "#dd7399", class: "\uD83C\uDFF0", rarity: "Rare", cash: [32e3, 1e5, 9e5, 9e6, 6e7], time: [4, 3, 3, 3, 2], price: [18e5, 19e6, 22e7, 24e8] },
                            { name: "Caterpillar", color: "#00c0f3", class: "\uD83C\uDFF0", rarity: "Epic", cash: [1e4, 7e4, 65e4, 75e5, 85e6], time: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], price: [42e5, 42e6, 54e7, 69e8] },
                            { name: "Mad Hatter", color: "#914f93", class: "\uD83C\uDFF0", rarity: "Epic", cash: [38e3, 25e4, 15e5, 14e6, 8e7], time: [3, 3, 2, 2, 1], price: [48e5, 48e6, 52e7, 66e8] },
                            { name: "King of Hearts", color: "#c62127", class: "\uD83C\uDFF0", rarity: "Legendary", cash: [8e4, 42e4, 68e5, 1e8, 15e8], time: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], price: [7e6, 11e7, 18e8, 3e10] },
                            { name: "Earth", color: "#416eb5", class: "\uD83D\uDE80", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [15e3, 45e3, 6e5, 65e5, 65e6], time: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], price: [1e6, 11e6, 15e7, 17e8] },
                            { name: "Meteor", color: "#c68c3c", class: "\uD83D\uDE80", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [23e3, 65e3, 7e5, 45e5, 2e7], time: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], price: [95e4, 13e6, 16e7, 16e8] },
                            { name: "Stars", color: "#19184d", class: "\uD83D\uDE80", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [1e4, 4e4, 2e5, 2e6, 18e6], time: [2, 2, 1, 1, 1], price: [14e5, 14e6, 15e7, 15e8] },
                            { name: "Alien", color: "#8dc63f", class: "\uD83D\uDE80", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [3e4, 1e5, 1e6, 11e6, 85e6], time: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], price: [15e5, 17e6, 19e7, 17e8] },
                            { name: "Planet", color: "#9dc6ea", class: "\uD83D\uDE80", rarity: "Rare", cash: [25e3, 1e5, 9e5, 9e6, 9e7], time: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], price: [2e6, 21e6, 21e7, 24e8] },
                            { name: "UFO", color: "#a15095", class: "\uD83D\uDE80", rarity: "Rare", cash: [17e3, 7e4, 7e5, 7e6, 7e7], time: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], price: [21e5, 23e6, 25e7, 28e8] },
                            { name: "Spaceship", color: "#ffcb29", class: "\uD83D\uDE80", rarity: "Epic", cash: [6e4, 32e4, 21e5, 15e6, 85e6], time: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], price: [48e5, 46e6, 54e7, 68e8] },
                            { name: "Astronaut", color: "#9bd4ee", class: "\uD83D\uDE80", rarity: "Legendary", cash: [45e3, 26e4, 25e5, 38e6, 55e7], time: [3, 3, 2, 2, 2], price: [65e5, 1e8, 17e8, 27e9] },
                            { name: "Lil Bot", color: "#3e564a", class: "\uD83E\uDD16", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [4e3, 12e3, 18e4, 19e5, 25e6], time: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], price: [73e4, 12e6, 13e7, 19e8] },
                            { name: "Lovely Bot", color: "#f179af", class: "\uD83E\uDD16", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [16e3, 65e3, 65e4, 48e5, 42e6], time: [3, 3, 3, 2, 2], price: [13e5, 14e6, 17e7, 16e8] },
                            { name: "Angry Bot", color: "#f1613a", class: "\uD83E\uDD16", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [22e3, 85e3, 8e5, 62e5, 65e6], time: [4, 4, 4, 3, 3], price: [12e5, 13e6, 15e7, 17e8] },
                            { name: "Happy Bot", color: "#51ba6b", class: "\uD83E\uDD16", rarity: "Uncommon", cash: [11e3, 45e3, 5e5, 25e5, 3e7], time: [2, 2, 2, 1, 1], price: [14e5, 15e6, 18e7, 24e8] },
                            { name: "Watson", color: "#d69b5a", class: "\uD83E\uDD16", rarity: "Rare", cash: [24e3, 1e5, 1e6, 1e7, 1e8], time: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], price: [2e6, 22e6, 24e7, 26e8] },
                            { name: "Buddy Bot", color: "#9dc6ea", class: "\uD83E\uDD16", rarity: "Rare", cash: [22e3, 95e3, 65e4, 65e5, 65e6], time: [3, 3, 2, 2, 2], price: [19e5, 21e6, 23e7, 25e8] },
                            { name: "Brainy Bot", color: "#9ecf7a", class: "\uD83E\uDD16", rarity: "Epic", cash: [5e4, 25e4, 21e5, 21e6, 17e7], time: [4, 3, 3, 3, 2], price: [5e6, 46e6, 5e8, 67e8] },
                            { name: "Mega Bot", color: "#d71f27", class: "\uD83E\uDD16", rarity: "Legendary", cash: [8e4, 43e4, 42e5, 62e6, 1e9], time: [5, 5, 3, 3, 3], price: [7e6, 12e7, 19e8, 35e9] }, ]

Solo busco la manera, no el código completo, y puede ser en cualquier lenguaje de programación pero que lo pueda pasar a la BD.



name
color
class
rarity




Chick
#ffcd05
\uD83C\udF3D
Common



Gracias de antemano

Vas a Chatgpt, le dices quiero una query para crear una base de datos e insertas los siguientes elementos y le pegas ese json

Este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas sobre problemas concretos de programación. Se requiere que hayas trabajado en el problema y tengas un código que analizar. No hacemos código a la medida.

Mi estimado, yo veo tu pregunta bastante válida, por favor edita tu pregunta y específica un tipo de base de datos, como MySQL, SQL Server, etc... Edita tu pregunta y específica lenguaje de programación, node.js, php, c#, java, etc. Si no quieres un lenguaje de programación en específico indica que no quiero un lenguaje de programación en específico.

@CristhianJavierUlloaCarmona. La pregunta va a ser cerrada pues no aporta ningún código que demuestre esfuerzo en buscar una solución.

El json es buen punto de partida, no te quito la razón pero es así

Ok, queremos un JSON meterlo hacia una BD SQL, que lenguaje quieres usar para eso?

@CandidMoe quiero contradecirte ahí, ya que, la pregunta PODRIA ser cerrada. El usuario aun puede volver y mejorar su pregunta, y nunca obtener un cierre de la misma. Lo correcto es esperar y votar en caso de ser necesario, Como solo han sido 4 horas, no veo por que cerrarla de inmediato, prefiero darle un dia al OP y ver que sucede.

@Excorpion. Nadie ha votado para cerrarla (todavía).

@Yussef Al igual que muchas (para no decir todas) las preguntas de este sitio. Pero no lo hemos hecho
